# How to get permission to upload images in my app?

Tags: java, android

Hi need to upload images into my app but can't display the window of permission for it, so I tried to upload the image without permission but the database gets null field in the image field and it seems that no permission is needed for the application cause it doesn't appears into the application settings anyway, need help please:
It's a coctail recipes app

1. you can login or register into it
2. in the home screen you can see some recipes
3. if you want you can search by categories in other screen
4. you can upload your recipe with an image (HERE IS THE PROBLEM) in other screen, but when i try to upload the image into the database, the field of the image stay as "null" so i tried to ask for permissions in the app but the windows asking for permissions to the user never appears so i got stucked there.

```
package com.example.asd;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBar;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultLauncher;
import androidx.activity.result.contract.ActivityResultContracts;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.List;

public class SubirRecetas extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText edtNombre, edtIngredientes, edtInstrucciones;
    private ImageButton btnImagen;
    private String imagenPath;
    private Button SubirRecetas;
    private Spinner spinnerCategoria;
    private int idUsuario; // Asigna el valor que corresponda
    private daoUsuario dao;

    private final ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> galleryLauncher = registerForActivityResult(
            new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
            result -> {
                if (result.getResultCode() == AppCompatActivity.RESULT_OK) {
                    Intent data = result.getData();
                    if (data != null) {
                        Uri uri = data.getData();
                        imagenPath = getPathFromUri(uri);
                        btnImagen.setImageURI(uri);
                    }
                }
            }
    );

    private static final int REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE_PERMISSION = 1;

    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        onBackPressed();
        return super.onSupportNavigateUp();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_subir_recetas);

        // Solicitar permisos
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M &&
                checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                    REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE_PERMISSION);
        } else {
            // Continuar con la inicialización de la actividad
            initializeActivity();
        }

        // Obtener el ID de usuario (de alguna manera, puede ser desde la actividad anterior)
        Intent intento = getIntent();
        if (intento != null) {
            idUsuario = intento.getIntExtra("idUsuario", -1);  // Asumiendo que "idUsuario" es la clave utilizada para pasar el ID
        }

        Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (b != null) {
            idUsuario = b.getInt("id");

        }
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbarB);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        assert actionBar != null;
        actionBar.setTitle("Subir Recetas");
        actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        dao = new daoUsuario(this);

        List<String> categoriasList = dao.selectCategorias();

        if (categoriasList.isEmpty()) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "No se encontraron categorías en la base de datos.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            // Manejar el caso en que no hay categorías disponibles
            return;
        }

        spinnerCategoria = findViewById(R.id.spinnerCategoria);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapterSpinner = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, categoriasList);
        adapterSpinner.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinnerCategoria.setAdapter(adapterSpinner);

        edtNombre = findViewById(R.id.NombreReceta);
        edtIngredientes = findViewById(R.id.Ingrediente);
        edtInstrucciones = findViewById(R.id.Descripcion);
        btnImagen = findViewById(R.id.imagen);
        SubirRecetas = findViewById(R.id.SubirRecetas);

        btnImagen.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            // Verificar el permiso antes de abrir la galería
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M &&
                    checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
                intent.setType("image/*");
                galleryLauncher.launch(intent);
            } else {
                // Solicitar permiso si no está concedido
                requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                        REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE_PERMISSION);
                Log.d("Permission", "Permission not granted. Requesting permission.");
            }

        });

        SubirRecetas.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            String nombre = edtNombre.getText().toString();
            String ingredientes = edtIngredientes.getText().toString();
            String instrucciones = edtInstrucciones.getText().toString();

            if (imagenPath == null || imagenPath.isEmpty()) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Seleccione una imagen", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }

            byte[] imagenBytes = convertirImagenBytes(Uri.parse(imagenPath));

            if (idUsuario == 0) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Debe autenticarse antes de subir una receta", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }

            String categoria = spinnerCategoria.getSelectedItem().toString();
            agregarReceta(nombre, ingredientes, instrucciones, imagenBytes, categoria);

            // Limpiar los campos después de subir la receta con éxito
            limpiarCampos();

        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        if (requestCode == REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE_PERMISSION) {
            // Verificar si el permiso fue concedido
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // Permiso concedido, continuar con la inicialización de la actividad
                initializeActivity();
            } else {
                // Permiso no concedido, mostrar un mensaje o tomar alguna acción
                Toast.makeText(this, "Permiso de almacenamiento no concedido", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }

    private void initializeActivity() {
        // Obtener el ID de usuario (de alguna manera, puede ser desde la actividad anterior)
        Intent intento = getIntent();
        if (intento != null) {
            idUsuario = intento.getIntExtra("idUsuario", -1);  // Asumiendo que "idUsuario" es la clave utilizada para pasar el ID
        }
    }
        private void limpiarCampos () {
            edtNombre.getText().clear();
            edtIngredientes.getText().clear();
            edtInstrucciones.getText().clear();
            btnImagen.setImageURI(null);
            spinnerCategoria.setSelection(0);
        }

        private String getPathFromUri (Uri uri){
            String[] projection = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);
            if (cursor != null) {
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
                String filePath = cursor.getString(column_index);
                cursor.close();
                return filePath;
            } else {
                return uri.getPath();
            }
        }

        private byte[] convertirImagenBytes (Uri uri){
            try {
                InputStream inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
                if (inputStream != null) {
                    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                    int bytesRead;
                    while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                        byteArrayOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                    }
                    inputStream.close();
                    return byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Error al abrir el flujo de entrada", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(this, "Error al convertir la imagen a bytes", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            return null;
        }

        private void agregarReceta (String nombre, String ingredientes, String instrucciones,
        byte[] imagenBytes, String categoria){
            if (nombre.isEmpty()) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "El nombre de la receta no puede estar vacío", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }

            try {
                int idCategoria = dao.obtenerIdCategoria(categoria);
                if (idCategoria != -1) {
                    dao.insertarReceta(idCategoria, idUsuario, nombre, ingredientes, instrucciones, imagenBytes);
                    Toast.makeText(this, "La receta ha sido subida con éxito", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Categoría no encontrada en la base de datos", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(this, "Error al subir la receta", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
```

Tried without permission but the database gets null in img field

Comment: You are doing it the wrong way. Here is Google recommended way you can refer https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting

Comment: Upload into your app? What would that be? Further you could tell the scenario the code/user follows.

Comment: My bad, it's a coctail recipes app
1) you can login or register into it
2) in the home screen you can see some recipes
3) if you want you can search by categories in other screen
4) you can upload your recipe with an image (HERE IS THE PROBLEM) in other screen, but when i try to upload the image into the database, the field of the image stay as "null" so i tried to ask for permissions in the app but the windows asking for permissions to the user never appears so i got stucked there.

Comment: Only nr 4 is relevant. And you should not have told that in a comment but in your post to inform the reader before he dives in your code. Please also avoid the word upload as you are uploading nothing to a server but just try to put some data in a local database. Please write -in your post- the scenario for nr 4 as we still dont know the steps that should be done in the code. You can also remove all imports.

Comment: Probably the user picked a .jpg file. You could put that file in your database. What i see is that you first make a bitmap out of it (you should have told that in your post, the scenario we wanna know before we deep in the code) and also the reason the made a bitmap. Realise that a bitmap can be 50 times more bytes then a jpg file and it is strange that you would put a bitmap in your database. We cannot see if you do as that important part of the code is lacking.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).